# Inno setup: reboot in post installation stage and continue setup on restart

Tags: inno-setup

I am creating a setup kit using Inno Setup. I have a special requirement to reboot the system in `[Code]` section. I know how to implement `PrepareToInstall()` and I have checked the example `CodePrepareToInstall.iss` provided in inno examples codes.

However, this does not work for me. As this reboot happens before Files section. I want to reboot the system in `CurStepChanged - ssPostInstall` stage and continue installation from that point on restart. (I tried calling `PrepareToInstall()` but it does not work.)

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe some tips from a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750880/inno-setup-restart-in-the-middle-of-setup-process

Comment: Thanks Lars, I have seen this question. But this is not what I want. It reboots the system before Files section. I want to reboot it in Post Installation stage.

Comment: In the answer to that post, Miral mentions using a subinstaller... could that be used after the reboot to provide the functionality you want?