# Inno Setup: restart during setup process won't start after reboot

Tags: windows, installation, registry, inno-setup, reboot

I've made a installer using Inno Setup, and  I need to restart computer after some files was run, 
so I used the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750880/inno-setup-restart-in-the-middle-of-setup-process).

The inno setup sample '*CodePrepareToInstall.iss*' works fine, so I used the code for my test installation but my installer don't start after
computer reboots.

Both installer (inno demo and my test) add a registry entry in '*HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce*', the only difference is 
the added value. My sting ist much longer than the added string from inno demo.

Is there a value legth limitation in registry/runonce?

```
Inno Demo Value:
"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Inno Setup Examples Output\setup.exe" /restart=1 /LANG=default /DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program" /GROUP="My Program"

My Installer Value:
"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Inno Setup Projekte\Treiber Test\bin\Driver Test Setup.exe" /restart=1 /LANG=german /DIR="C:\Driver" /GROUP="Driver Test Setup" /TYPE="full" /COMPONENTS="1234driverinstaller,audio,bluetooth,chipset,devicepowermanager,gps,inputmanagementservice,modem,lan,1234powerplan,touchscreen,vga,wlan,wwan,1234products"
```

Comment: Does the command work, if you run it manually?

Comment: Yes, if I copy the value from registry and past it into run, the installer comes up and works fine. If I cut the value after the "/Group" Section it will also run fine after computer restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Windows has a 256 character limit on commands ran from the RunOnce registry in HKLU or HKLM.

So I decided to create a batch file that starts my installer and delete it self afterwards. So I just had to pass the path of the batch to the RunOnce registry.

InnoScript:

```
procedure CreateRunOnceEntry;
var
    RunOnceData: String;
begin
    RunOnceData := 'echo off' + #13#10;
    RunOnceData := RunOnceData + 'start "" ';
    RunOnceData := RunOnceData + Quote(ExpandConstant('{srcexe}')) + ' /restart=1';
    RunOnceData := AddParam(RunOnceData, 'LANG', ExpandConstant('{language}'));
    RunOnceData := AddParam(RunOnceData, 'DIR', Quote(WizardDirValue));
    RunOnceData := AddParam(RunOnceData, 'GROUP', Quote(WizardGroupValue));
    if WizardNoIcons then
        RunOnceData := AddSimpleParam(RunOnceData, 'NOICONS');
    RunOnceData := AddParam(RunOnceData, 'TYPE', Quote(WizardSetupType(False)));
    RunOnceData := AddParam(RunOnceData, 'COMPONENTS', Quote(WizardSelectedComponents(False)));
    RunOnceData := AddParam(RunOnceData, 'TASKS', Quote(WizardSelectedTasks(False)));
    RunOnceData := RunOnceData + #13#10 + 'start /b cmd.exe /c del %0' + #13#10 + 'exit';

    SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}\StartInstallation.cmd'), RunOnceData, True);

    if not IsWin64 then
        RegWriteStringValue(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce', RunOnceName, ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}\StartInstallation.cmd'));
    if IsWin64 then
        RegWriteStringValue(HKLM, 'Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce', RunOnceName, ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}\StartInstallation.cmd'));
end;
```

Batch file:

```
echo off
start "" "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Inno Setup Projekte\Treiber Test\bin\Driver Test Setup.exe" /restart=1 /LANG=german /DIR="C:\Driver" /GROUP="Driver Test Setup" /TYPE="full" /COMPONENTS="1234driverinstaller,audio,bluetooth,chipset,devicepowermanager,gps,inputmanagementservice,modem,lan,1234powerplan,touchscreen,vga,wlan,wwan,1234products"
start /b cmd.exe /c del %0
exit
```

Comment: We should report this as a bug because this can happen quite easily. As a workaround for Inno Setup implementation I would suggest using task  scheduler. P.S. do not ever access `Wow6432Node`. Use `HKLM32`, or `HKLM64` root keys if you want to access certain registry view.

Comment: Yes you are right, I'll report this as bug and use HKLM32 or HKLM64 insted. Thanks =)